# Hover hyperlinks with this jQuery-animated menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm currently working on my exam project, and I have this [animated jQuery navigation](http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/how-to-make-a-smooth-animated-menu-with-jquery/).

I would like to make the text-color of the  white, both when I have mouse over the  itself AND when I have the mouse over the menu icon which is shown when you mouse over the `<li>` elements.

I have tried everything, but haven't found a solution for it.

[Demo](http://mul100.itkn.dk/Exam/index.html)

[Stylesheet](http://mul100.itkn.dk/Exam/style.css)

Example: If you have your mouse over *Forside* (text is white), and then take your mouse over the *white house icon*, you'll see that the text change from white to black. I want it to stay white.
NOTE: Dont mind the crappy colors or layout, lol, right now I'm just focusing on the menu.

Anyone has a fix for this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the CSS code?

Comment: can yo post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above does work:

li:hover a { color: white !important; }

You could also surround the anchor tags with a div with a class of say, "target", and then target the div using jQuery to programmatically set a class with the color property set to white:

```
$('.target').hover(function(){
$(this).children(':first-child').toggleClass('className');
}, function(){
$(this).children(':first-child').toggleClass('className');
});
```

Something like that... but the CSS way is much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I didn't imagine this being such a hard task. The following might not be an elegant solution, but it works:

`li:hover a { color: white !important; }`